# C# Check if filename ends with pattern

Tags: c#, regex, filenames

With a list of file names like below:

- foo.pdf
- foo(1).pdf
- foo(2).pdf
- foo(321).pdf

How can we check if the file name ends with the pattern (n).extension? 
And if it does, how to get only the filename without the (n) part?

Comment: Have you tried something? Please, post the relevant code.

Comment: This can help you a lot: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: Why not use the built in IO functions?

Comment: I would recommend using the System.IO functions to filter on all files that have the extension.  Then use the FileInfo class to inspect the filename to see if it contains the value.

Comment: @Geek Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work

```
void Main()
{
    string test = "file(321).pdf";
    string pattern = @"\([0-9]+\)\.";
    bool m = Regex.IsMatch(test, pattern);
    if(m == true)
       test = Regex.Replace(test, pattern, ".");

   Console.WriteLine(test);
}
```